# why does my ObservableCollection not filter

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, icollectionview

i have a WPF desktop app.

I load an ObservableCollection with a list of objects.

I use the ICollectionView object to 'wrap' a filter around this ObservableCollection .

I set the filter and refresh but it does nto work so:

```
public class DataFilters : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICollectionView _UserMappedRolesView { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles> _UserMappedRoles;
    public ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles> UserMappedRoles
    {
        get
        {
            _UserMappedRolesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_UserMappedRoles);
            _UserMappedRolesView.Filter = UserMappedRolesFilter;
            _UserMappedRolesView.Refresh();
            return _UserMappedRoles;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserMappedRoles = value;
        }
    }

    public void LoadUserMappedRoles()
    {
        var baseData = InformedWorkerBusinessService.UserMappedRoles.Get();
        var modelData =
            from data in baseData
            select new UserMappedRoles
            {
                Enabled = 1,
                Login = data.Login,
                UserMappedRolesRef = data.UserMappedRolesRef,
                UserRoleRef = data.UserRoleRef

            };
        _UserMappedRoles = new ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles>(modelData);
    }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    private bool UserMappedRolesFilter(object item)
    {
        UserMappedRoles UserMappedRole = item as UserMappedRoles;

        if (UserMappedRole.Login== Login)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and my test script:

```
UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.Models.HeartBeat VM = new UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.Models.HeartBeat();
VM.CommonData.DataFilters = new UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.Models.DataFilters();
VM.CommonData.DataFilters.LoadUserMappedRoles();
var data = VM.CommonData.DataFilters.UserMappedRoles;
VM.CommonData.DataFilters.Login = "David";
var filtered = VM.CommonData.DataFilters.UserMappedRoles;
```

I know my data only contains oUserMappedRoles where the Login name is 'Andy' so, by setting the Login filter name to 'David' I expect to get no records back.

I have set breakpoints everywhere and everyline of code gets 'hit'.

Have I (obviously) implemented this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a very good practise to change an ObservableCollection, it should really be defined as a readonly collection that you can clear and update, but not replace it. Wpf doesn't handle changes that well when the list gets removed (also think about possible other NotifyPropertyChanged events that might be bound to it)

Comment: @Icepickle Hi, thanks for your comment. But that is what my code does. it loads the observable collection with everything just once and then i perform filters on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the ICollectionView that gets filtered, not the ObservableCollection.

So you should bind to the ICollectionView property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserMappedRolesView}" DisplayMemberPath="Login" />
```

...or look for the filtered items in this one:

```
var filtered = VM.CommonData.DataFilters.UserMappedRolesView;
```

You also need to refresh the CollectionView whenever you want to re-apply the filter, i.e. whenever your Login property is set to a new value. Something like this:

```
public class DataFilters : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICollectionView _UserMappedRolesView;
    public ICollectionView UserMappedRolesView
    {
        get { return _UserMappedRolesView; }
        set { _UserMappedRolesView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles> _UserMappedRoles;
    public ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles> UserMappedRoles
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserMappedRoles;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserMappedRoles = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            UserMappedRolesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_UserMappedRoles);
            UserMappedRolesView.Filter = UserMappedRolesFilter;
            UserMappedRolesView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public void LoadUserMappedRoles()
    {
        var baseData = InformedWorkerBusinessService.UserMappedRoles.Get();
        var modelData =
            from data in baseData
            select new UserMappedRoles
            {
                Enabled = 1,
                Login = data.Login,
                UserMappedRolesRef = data.UserMappedRolesRef,
                UserRoleRef = data.UserRoleRef

            };
        UserMappedRoles = new ObservableCollection<UserMappedRoles>(modelData);
    }


    private string _login;
    public string Login
    {
        get { return _login; }
        set { _login = value; _UserMappedRolesView.Refresh(); }
    }


    private bool UserMappedRolesFilter(object item)
    {
        UserMappedRoles UserMappedRole = item as UserMappedRoles;
        if (UserMappedRole.Login == Login)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```